# Google App Engine instance crashing with ErrorCode 121

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My GAE app suddenly stopped working last friday. I tried several times to start an instance in background, (both using cron and manually) but after a minute since the instance starts I get this error:

```
/cron/spreadsheet 500 4660ms 0kb instance=0 AppEngine-Google; 
(+http://code.google.com/appengine)

0.1.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2013:12:40:05 -0800] "GET /cron/spreadsheet HTTP/1.1" 500 0 - 
"AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
"backend.myclimagest.appspot.com" ms=4661 cpu_ms=692 queue_name=__cron 
task_name=5ed789ec52683cb170ed3c2cc4ec48c9 pending_ms=3651 exit_code=121 
instance=0 

W 2013-02-17 12:40:05.268
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, 
causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used 
for the next request to your application. (Error code 121)
```

I don't know what to do since this error code is undocumented. I also tried to redeploy but no luck. Are you experiencing the same problem and have you maybe found a solution?
I don't think it matters but the app is developed in Java using Eclipse.
The app is in production so I really need to solve this issue as quickly as I can.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It seems your App Engine scheduler got problem. Try this, Removing the automatic settings from Performance settings which seeems to help. [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/d36A_yvdoHo)

Check this Official Google page too [Managing Your App's Resource Usage](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/managing-resources)

Comment: I tried setting **Idle Instances: ( Automatic – 950 )
    Pending Latency: ( Automatic – 14.5s )**
and it worked for something like 70 minutes, then the same error appeared and the instance vanished.

Comment: can you try redeploying your app and let me know what the status

Comment: redeployed, nothing changed. It seems to work for a while then I suddenly get the error again.

Comment: to my analysis its seems this problem reported as bug you can create an issue or follow up this [Google Groups Issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!search/GAE$20Error$20code$20121$202013/google-appengine-stackoverflow/6glEJbSCcng/LcUYlPmfxiIJ)

Comment: I managed to get it to work again creating a new backend and launching the instance on that one. Nonetheless, the issue is still present in the original backend (which I also tried to delete and redeploy with the same name). By now it looks like the only thing you can do to eradicate the problem is to report the issue to Google and wait for their answer.